# How do I add additional information to a Pivot (using Fluent)?

Tags: swift, vapor

In Vapor, we can create many-to-many relationships by creating a `Pivot<U, T>` object, where `U` and `T` are the models that we want to link together. So if I want to create a system where `User`s can have many `File`s and many `File`s can belong to many `User`s, I'd associate them like this:

```
var alice = User(name: "Alice")
try! alice.save()
var sales = File(name: "sales.xclx")
try! sales.save()

var pivot = Pivot<User, File>(alice, sales)
try! pivot.save()
```

What I can't figure out for the life of me is how would I make a `Pivot<User, File>` contain additional information? For example, I'd like to know when was this file associated associated to Alice, or what permissions she has over it.

On a Relational database, Fluent creates this table for the `Pivot<User, File>` type.

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But I'd like the ability to represent something like this:

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date    | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| perms   | varchar | NO   |     | READ    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 6):

The `Pivot<U, T>` object can be thought of as the "bare minimum" required fields for a pivoted relation like `siblings`.

If you want to add custom fields to this table, you can create your own class to act as the pivot as long as it has the required elements:

- Table name for `Foo` and `Bar` is `bar_foo` (lowercase, alphabetically ordered)
- There exists at least the three columns: `id`, `bar_id`, `foo_id`

In other words, the table created by your pivot class must have at least the elements a `Pivot<Foo, Bar>` preparation would have created.

With this done, you can create new pivot relations by creating and saving instances of your pivot class.

When `.siblings()` relations are called on your models that use this pivot table, the default `Pivot<U, T>` will still be created to perform the fetch. But, this won't create any issues since the required fields are present on the pivot table.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but a few questions remain. You say to create a new class to act as a pivot, does that mean I should subclass it? I'd appreciate it if you left a small example.

Comment: Can't subclass it since it isn't `open`. Do: class MyPivot: Model { }

Comment: Well, that does answer that I have to create my own Pivot based on Model rather than subclassing `Pivot`. Guess I will explore that idea a little bit further and see how it goes.

Comment: if we would created our model so that Pivot function will use we would have to modify the table name in the database because there will an `s` of plural and Pivot creates a table concatenating  table names without `s` at the end

Answer (score 4):

so after having the same problem described by Andy and asking for a solution on the Vapor Slack I was redirected here.

My implementation (using PostgreSQL) of the solution proposed by Tanner can be found [here](https://github.com/floriankrueger/Vapor-Movies-Example/tree/09d9e92328cf401ec10af75031d399b676bb789e)

The key is the `Rating` model:

- it’s a plain `Model` subclass
- it has an `entity` name of `movie_user` (as described by Tanner the names of the relating models in alphabetical order)
- it has the fields `userId` (mapping to `"user_id"`) and `movieId` (mapping to `"movie_id"`), both are of type `Node`.
- in `prepare(Database)` it again uses the name `"movie_user"` and defines the Id fields as `Int`s.

With that set up you can define the following relationship convenience methods:

On `Movie`: all raters

```
extension Movie {
    func raters() throws -> Siblings<User> {
        return try siblings()
    }
}
```

On `User`: all rated movies

```
extension User {
    func ratedMovies() throws -> Siblings<Movie> {
        return try siblings()
    }
}
```

A new rating for a movie (for a user) can be added like this:

```
ratings.post() { request in
    var rating = try Rating(node: request.json)
    try rating.save()
    return rating
}
```

As `Rating` is a Model subclass, we can create it directly from the requests JSON. This requires the client to send a JSON document that conforms to the node structure of the `Rating` class:

```
{
    "user_id": <the rating users id>,
    "movie_id": <the id of the movie to be rated>,
    "stars": <1-5 or whatever makes sense for your usecase>
}
```

To get all actual `Rating`s for a given movie, you seem to have to resolve the relationship manually (at least I think so, maybe somebody can give me a hint on how to do this better):

```
let ratings = try Rating.query().filter("movie_id", movieId).all()
```

Also, there seems to be no way of somehow calculating an average on the database right now. I would have loved something like this to work:

```
// this is now how it works
let averageRating = try Rating.query().filter("movie_id", movieId).average("stars")
```

So I hope this helps anybody coming across this problem. And thanks to all the wonderful people who contribute to the Vapor project!

Thx to @WERUreo for pointing out that the part where a rating is created was missing.

Comment: The one question I still have is, how do you add Ratings?  I saw there was a POST route for ratings, but what JSON would you need to pass it in order to add ratings to specific movies from specific users?

Comment: thx for pointing this out. I updated the answer. Basically, you're just POSTing the whole relationship: `user_id`, `movie_id`, `stars`. But that's only one way of doing it. You could also go for something like `POST /users/<user_id>/movies/<movie_id> {"stars": 4}` (or the other way around) and then assemble the relationship in the request handler.